# How to get error from extern java program that calls with process command

Tags: .net, process

I have a vb.net application that calls a java program with the process command. That works fine. But I try to get the clear text exception from the java program. For this I set

```
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
…
Dim myStreamReader As StreamReader = process.StandardError
Dim errorMsg As String = myStreamReader.ReadLine
process.WaitForExit()
…
```

This code threw an exception: “The specified executable is not a valid Win32 application.” Is there another alternative to get the exception or how can I solve the error?

edit 1:

I call the Java program in this way:

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
startInfo.FileName = "JavaProgramName.jar"
process.StartInfo.Verb = "java -jar"
startInfo.Arguments = stringParam
Process.Start(startInfo)
```

Solution 1 :

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
startInfo.FileName = """c:\...\java.exe"" –jar """ (read from HKCR)
startInfo.Arguments = "JavaProgramName.jar" & stringParam 
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
process = Process.Start(startInfo)
Dim myStreamReader As StreamReader = p.StandardError
Dim errorMsg As String = myStreamReader.ReadLine
```

Solution 2, this works too:

```
startInfo.FileName = = """c:\...\java.exe"" -jar JavaProgramName.jar " & stringParam
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
process = Process.Start(startInfo)
Dim myStreamReader As StreamReader = p.StandardError
Dim errorMsg As String = myStreamReader.ReadLine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, java "executables" aren't valid Win32 applications. You have to run

```
java yourJavaApp.jar
```

Because you turned off `UseShellExecute`, you can only run actual executables - for example, with shell execute, you can `Process.Start("MyDocument.doc")`, but without it, you need to explicitly start Word with `MyDocument.doc` as an argument.

Of course, this may mean you'll need to find the path to a Java installation. When you use shell execute, it looks in registry to find which application is used for that particular file extension - in this case, `HKCR\jarfile\shell\open\command`. That might be a good place to start :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In HKCR\jarfile\shell\open\command it is the correct path to the javax.exe. Now I change the 
process.StartInfo.Verb = "java -jar" to process.StartInfo.Verb = resultFromHKCR, is this what you mean? The behavior didn’t change. I can use the java program results, but if I activate the UseShellExecute… it comes the same error.

Comment: @naro That again only works with `UseShellExecute`, which prevents you from redirecting the I/O streams. You need to have the `java.exe` executable as the FileName, and the `jar` file as an argument (with proper escaping and quoting).